# d3 changing link distance by clicking on nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I wanted to change the distance of nodes from each other based on clicking the nodes.Each node can be initially assigned some properties like `score1`, `score2`, `score3` etc. Now the user should be able to click on any node of his choice and select a value from the options which would result in a change in the force layout based on the scores. For e.g. if I choose a node (say node no.5) and select the property `score3`, then all the other nodes should be laid out based on the difference from their own `score3` values to the score of the node no. 5. Could somebody guide me how I can do this?

Comment: In the on click event handler, set the link distance accordingly and restart the force layout.

Comment: I am having trouble with setting the link distance. How do i make that particular node as the reference point with which all the other nodes can set the distance?

Comment: You can't do that, that's not how the force layout works. Have a look at [the documentation for `linkDistance()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#linkDistance).